# Describing shaking hands using both hands

Tags: word-request

How can we describe this way of shaking hands?

[image: image of someone grasping another person’s hands with both of theirs]

> The men are using both hands to shake hands.

This doesn't sound coherent. But I'm unable to find another construction.

Comment: "The men shake with both hands"?

Comment: I found: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/7415/how-to-describe-the-following-greeting-gestures

Answer (score 7):

When people shake hands, they usually grasp each other's extended right hand and, very often, the hands will be moved up and down. The action in the picture looks more like clasping than shaking. One man is clasping the other's hands with his own. When clasping, no movement need take place.

Comment: ...move _them_ up and down, or is **bobbing** involved where you're from?

Comment: Nothing about swords? Or even driving on the left-hand side or right-hand side?